# django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name does not resolve. How to solve this issue?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Can some body help me solve this issue. Why am i getting this error? I have db in .env host and links, network in docker-compose file too. I am not being to figure out where the issue is being raised.
Here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.9"
   
volumes:
  dbdata:

networks:
  django:
    driver: bridge

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/home/django
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: gunicorn Django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    container_name: django_web
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      - django

  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 5430:5432
    networks:
      - django
    container_name: django_db
```

here is my .env with database settings

```
DB_USER=admin
DB_NAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=admin
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=5432
DB_SCHEMA=public
CONN_MAX_AGE=60
```

Comment: What's the exact command you're running that produces the error?  (Are you trying to run database migrations from outside of Docker, or getting this error during the image build?)  The `links:` option is obsolete and activates an archaic Docker networking mode; does removing it make any difference?

Comment: i get this error running `docker compose up --build `

Comment: Is it during the build phase or when the container starts up?  Can you `docker-compose build` successfully?  If not, what is in your image's Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **when you are using**:

```
docker compose up --build
```

As [docker compose document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/) describes :

| flag | reference |
| --- | --- |
| --build | Build images **before starting containers**. |

That means that during the build time **there is no "db" container running**, so there is **no possible to exist a "db" host name**.

A suggestion would be to to **not engage any DB transaction during the build phase**.
You can make any database "rendering" **as a seeding process in your app start**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your .env states this:

```
DB_HOST=db
```

but your docker compose file states this:

```
    container_name: django_db
```

In my opinion these should be the same.